# Google Firestore Request had insufficient authentication scopes

Tags: php, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm following official [firestore quick start tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart)  here is my code -

```
use Google\Cloud\Firestore\FirestoreClient;
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
ini_set("track_errors", 1);
ini_set("html_errors", 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);


initialize();



function initialize()
{
    // Create the Cloud Firestore client
    $db = new FirestoreClient();
    printf('Created Cloud Firestore client with default project ID.' . PHP_EOL);
    $docRef = $db->collection('users')->document('lovelace');
    $docRef->set([
        'first' => 'Ada',
        'last' => 'Lovelace',
        'born' => 1815
    ]);
    printf('Added data to the lovelace document in the users collection.' . PHP_EOL);

}
```

I'm getting this error message Uncaught Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\ServiceException: { "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.", "code": 7, "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",

My database rules are

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should adapt your rules as follows:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Note however, that with these rules you "allow read/write access to all users under any conditions". It is highly recommended to change them when going to production, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started

Comment: Where did you change it, in the Firebase console?

Comment: On firebase console  under my project  under database  there's  a rule tab. I changed it there

Comment: Stange... Can you retry please. It may take a bit of time to update.

Comment: I think I might not defined correct project as default project. I'm looking for way to define default project

Comment: Maybe start with a brand new project.

Comment: @CodeBird Hello, did you have time to try with a new project?